# How to change layout of views between landscape and portrait mode?

Tags: ios, xcode

In portrait mode I have four views on top of one another from the top to the bottom of the view controller (see image).

[image: portrait view]

I then want to change the position of the views relative to one another when the device transitions to landscape (see image two).[image: landscape view]

I want view 4 to move alongside views 2 and 3 and them all the sit below view 1.

Some of the layout conditions:

- view 1 is attached to the top of the view controller in both landscape and portrait.
- view 4 is attached to the left, right and bottom margins of the view controller in portrait mode.
- Views 2, 3 & 4 are centered horizontally within the portrait view.

What is the best method to achieve the different layouts?

Would the most elegant solution be to make a reference to the constraints in the view controllers code and activate and deactivate them in viewWillTransition? Or is there a way to use vary for traits to achieve this (I can imagine views 2, 3 & 4 being centered horizontally would make this hard to achieve, as well as adding the new constraints for view 4 in landscape mode)?

Comment: 'vary for traits' is the size class of XCode 8. However if you add one constraint to a certain size class it gets added to all of them. you can only modify currently existing constraints which doesnt help when view 4 needs a new set of constraints.

Comment: I think using viewWillTransition is probably the preferred method but wasnt sure if anyone is aware of a better way to do this

Comment: "Vary for Trails" was removed in Xcode 13.  See this excellent video by @heavyguidence on how to change constraints for different size classes in Xcode 13 and on: [youtube.com/watch?v=pZuNhxR_uRg](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pZuNhxR_uRg).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

We used to set up different sets of constraints and activate/deactivate them based upon orientation change. But nowadays can use size classes and "vary for traits".

For example, I start with a simple view and choose a compact width size class and then choose "Vary for traits":

[image]

I then add the appropriate constraints and click on "Done varying":

[image]

I then choose a "regular width size class" and repeat the process ("Vary for traits", add the constraints, click on "Done varying":

[image]

You then end up with a scene that will have a completely different set of constraints active for compact width size classes and regular width size classes. I.e. when I run the app, if the device rotates, the new constraints are activated:

[image]

For more information, see WWDC 2016 videos on adaptive layouts:

- https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/222
- https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/233

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, so is it possible to move the views in vary for traits without affecting the other size classes (e.g. switch to landscape, move the red and blue views to side by side and then add constraints)?

Comment: Yes, when you choose a new size class, move the views where you want them, add constraints, and you're done. I think there must be something I'm missing in your question: You must be having some problem with size classes that I'm not understanding. Perhaps you can explain what problem you're having with size class approach...

Comment: Don't use size classes to determine device orientation.  Size class ("compact" and "regular") and device orientation ("portrait" and "landscape") are not related.  Currently, all iPad size classes are "regular" and do not change when the device is rotated.  With iPhones; in portrait mode some models are "compact" width and some are "regular" width and so will behave differently upon rotation, if you are relying on detecting size class changes.

Comment: Sure, but one generally shouldn’t be using device orientation to figure out how the views should be laid out, either. E.g. just because an iPad is in landscape orientation doesn’t mean you have the full width of the device. You might be in split view multitasking where the device is in landscape mode, but you still have a narrow portion of the screen allotted to your app. Size classes are a useful, but imperfect, way to handle this. Sometimes you do your own, more refined detection of the layout. But in split view multitasking world, relying on device orientation is generally a bad practice.

Comment: Great answer Rob, however a question with "vary for traits", how would I do this if I wanted one layout for iPad portrait and the other layout for iPad horizontal given that their wR hR for both portrait and landscape - is something like this achievable in storyboard ?

Answer (score 1):

I use arrays of constraints and activate/deactivate according to orientation.

```
var p = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
var l = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
var initialOrientation = true
var isInPortrait = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // add any subviews here
    view.turnOffAutoResizing()        
    // add constraints here....
    //    common constraints you can set their isActive = true
    //    otherwise, add in to portrait(p) and landscape(l) arrays
}

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    if initialOrientation {
        initialOrientation = false
        if view.frame.width > view.frame.height {
            isInPortrait = false
        } else {
            isInPortrait = true
        }
        view.setOrientation(p, l)
    } else {
        if view.orientationHasChanged(&isInPortrait) {
            view.setOrientation(p, l)
        }
    }
}
extension UIView {
    public func turnOffAutoResizing() {
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        for view in self.subviews as [UIView] {
           view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }
    }
    public func orientationHasChanged(_ isInPortrait:inout Bool) -> Bool {
        if self.frame.width > self.frame.height {
            if isInPortrait {
                isInPortrait = false
                return true
            }
        } else {
            if !isInPortrait {
                isInPortrait = true
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }
    public func setOrientation(_ p:[NSLayoutConstraint], _ l:[NSLayoutConstraint]) {
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(l)
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(p)
        if self.bounds.width > self.bounds.height {
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate(l)
        } else {
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate(p)
        }
    }
}
```

My needs to distinguish portrait or landscape **require** using something other than size classes, as my app is universal and iPad (unless using split or slide out  view) is *always* normal size. Also, you may get use `viewWillTransistion(toSize:)` or `viewDidLoadSubviews()` instead of 'viewWillLoadSubviews()` - but always test, as these may be executed more than once on an orientation change!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, ideally I would like to do this via the storyboard but this would be a good alternative if it cant be done via the storyboard!

Comment: You *can* do it via storyboards, but remember that IB is merely a "design time" tool. What that means (I faced this) is that testing out an orientation change is tedious if not impossible, particularly for iPads.

Answer (score 0):

**Xcode 13**

Xcode 13 removed "Vary for Traits" and replaced it with the ability to install/uninstall constraints for different size classes.  Here's an update to @Rob's answer, using the new process.

I'm going to use the term orientation, for ease of explanation, but it's really size class.  For example portrait orientation on an iPhone is generally regular height/compact width.  Landscape on an iPhone is generally compact height/regular width.

First, set all constraints for one orientation.  In this case the red and blue views are constrained to the edges of the safe area or each other.  I gave the blue view a 1:1 ratio.
[image]

Then go through each constraint that needs to change with orientation and uninstall the constraint for the other orientation (size class).  I'll demonstrate with the blue view's leading alignment constraint which changes from the safe area's leading edge in portrait to the red view's trailing edge in landscape.

On the blue view's leading alignment constraint, select the plus sign next to "Installed" and chose Width: Any, Height: Compact (ie. landscape).
[image]

Select "Add Variation" and uncheck the new variation (next to "hC").  You're basically telling Xcode not to use this leading alignment constraint for compact height (landscape).
[image]

Now, change orientation in Interface Builder, and add a constraint between blue's leading edge and red's trailing edge.

Note: If the views disappear off screen, you can add new constraints by control-dragging between the views in the outline on the left.  Eventually, all views should appear as you expect in both orientations.
[image]

Select the new constraint and add a new variation for Width: Any, Height: Regular (ie. portrait).
[image]

Uncheck the new variation (next to "hR"), telling Xcode not to use this leading alignment constraint for regular height (portrait).
[image]

If a constraint doesn't change with orientation, then there will only be one "Installed" constraint for both orientations. For example, the blue view's trailing and bottom edges are constrained to the safe area's respective edges in both orientations.

Also note, the icons next to the constraints in the outline on the left are blue if they apply to the current orientation in Interface Builder, and gray if they don't apply to the current orientation.

[image]

Comment: Nice answer, however a question, how would I do this if I wanted one layout for iPad portrait and the other layout for iPad horizontal given that their wR hR for both portrait and landscape - is something like this achievable in storyboard ?