# iOS Constraints - Autolayout

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, autolayout, constraints

I'm practicing iOS development with Swift. I was doing the constraints - autolayout part. So, I'm like getting the idea of constraints pretty much, but I got a problem when in landscape mode and maybe in portrait too. I'll show you what I'm doing right now.

The problem is that I can't figure out how to stretch both blocks in landscape. One of the screenshots shows they are overlapping each other. Would be ok if they are one over the other.

I was checking already size classes which looks promising for learning

The pictures I'm attaching are for comparing so you can see what I'm doing wrong and what should I do instead:

[iPhone 7 - Portrait](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZPgu.png)

[iPhone 7 - Landscape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1aKS.png)

Thanks guys in advance

Comment: You can use "size classes" and "vary for traits", e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42319068/1271826.

Comment: There isn't a question here. What is your goal, which appearance falls short of it, and how?

Comment: You right @BaseZen. I'm going to edit the post. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of giving constant width, you can try adding leading and trailing constraints of boxes to superview, it will handle stretch in landscape mode and even for other devices like ipad, iphone.
Also you should try putting boxes in Scrollview if you want to retain the heights of boxes, (and remove bottom layout guide.top constraint for pink box. to avoid overlapping)